# The response to 'GET_LIST' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to use the [ra-data-simple-rest data provider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#usage).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, fetchUtils, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';
import { PostList } from './Posts';

const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:8000');

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

The react-admin listens to http://localhost:3000/#/posts

Api is running on : http://localhost:8000/posts which returns response as.

```
$response = new JsonResponse($output);
$response->headers->set('Content-Range', 'posts 0-0/5');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");
```

which retuns something as

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Hello world",
            "body": "Hello world"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Hello world",
            "body": "Hello world"
        }
    ],
    "total": 2
}
```

I am getting an error as

> The response to 'GET_LIST' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'GET_LIST'

If the `data` key is removed as

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Hello world",
        "body": "Hello world"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Hello world",
        "body": "Hello world"
    }
]
```

is getting the result.

Comment: A few more changes made to support CORS .

Comment: _For somereason it shows Failed to fetch_ where?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. `Failed to Fetch` was shown on red colour and it was due to more CORS related issue. So added appropriate headers. Current issue is with `The response to 'GET_LIST' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'GET_LIST'`

Answer (score 11):

Finally I understood this is working as expected by react-admin.

The problem was in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#response-format) I noticed

[image]

which confused me.

Looking more into the https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/1b6967f3367b13a6675de7047bd9385dc36a8db5/packages/ra-data-simple-rest/src/index.js#L118  I understood the data is rebuild by the provider.

Comment: Yep. Do you see any way we can improve the documentation or something? Also, you can mark your answer as "self answered"

Comment: > Do you see any way we can improve the documentation or something?

I was re-reading this today, "React-admin expects responses from Data Providers to be objects with a data property."

I think I missed to clearly recognize it is talking about Data Provider and not the url that returns the response. May be make the Data Provider bold, so it is highlighted clearly ?

> Also, you can mark your answer as "self answered"

Where can you mark this ? I didn't find that option ie why. Mostly I don't like answering my own, but answering this may help others ie the only reason I wrote it.

Comment: This answer helped me, @Kmaschta I think maybe a note in https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html under the Usage section where it mentions the Simple REST data provider would be helpful; something like "note that the `ra-data-simple-rest` package automatically handles creating the object with attribute `data`".

Answer (score 1):

I face same issue , after check my API response,I understand there is one field missing in object:

```
{ "data": [ { "id": "1", "title": "Hello world", "body": "Hello world" }, { "title": "Hello world", "body": "Hello world" } ], "total": 2 }
```

id is missing in second obj. that's why i face the issue

Any one who face this issue please check all fields in your API response.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you explain your answer? You check your API and you found (something, so expose which one) missin in... A Screenshot will help.

Comment: `{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Hello world",
            "body": "Hello world"
        },
        {
            
            "title": "Hello world",
            "body": "Hello world"
        }
    ],
    "total": 2
}`  id is missing in second obj. that's why i face the issue

Comment: please check the answer mentioned above.