# Error: The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. | React Admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I`m trying to fetch posts from "http://localhost:5001/posts".

I'm using react-admin but with my own api, this is the "dataprovider" for the frontend:

```
import jsonServerProvider from "ra-data-json-server";
const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider("http://localhost:5001");
```

on the backend this is my code:

```
const app = express();

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());


// get posts
app.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find();
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

full error message:

**Error: The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?**

How do I set the X-Total-Count header for the GET Request?

Comment: you should count the number of posts in the database then write this before send back the response res.set("X-Total-Count" , numberOfPosts);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Express, you can specify headers on the response using the `header` method that's on the `res` object.

Try something along the lines of:

```
app.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find();

    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Total-Count')
    res.header('X-Total-Count', posts.length)
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: worked. now i have a different error though hahah. "The response to 'getList' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for 'getList'"

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Backend
    let data : any = {};
    //...find()
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Total-Count')
    res.header('X-Total-Count', document.length)
    res.status(202).json(document); // Incorrect .json({ data })

    // Frontend custom data provider
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1';
    const httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson;
    const dataProvider = {
      getList: (resource, params) => {
          const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
          const { field, order } = params.sort;
          const query = {
              sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
              range: JSON.stringify([(page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage - 1]),
              filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
          };
          const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;

          return httpClient(url).then(({ headers, json }) => ({
              //data: json,
              data: json.map(resource => ({ ...resource, id: resource._id }) ),
              //total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
              total: parseInt(headers.get('X-Total-Count'))
          }));
      }
    }




If u like my case, u need to write your custom data provider

Our topic may be repeated [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297317/the-response-to-get-list-must-be-like-data-but-the-received-data][1]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).